# Override logging settings when running a test from Eclipse JUnit plugin?

Tags: eclipse, junit, log4j

Is there any easy way of overriding log levels (in my case log4j) when running a test from Eclipse JUnit plugin?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231773/specifying-a-custom-log4j-properties-file-for-all-of-junit-tests-run-from-eclips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a `log4j.xml` configuration file that fits your needs and put the directory with that file to your run configuration classpath - or use an other possibility to activate this configuration as described [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit).

Comment: Thanks, I guessed this was the case but was hoping for a more integrated way in the JUnit runner plugin. Thing is that I have to add this to all run configurations that are auto-created when I quick-run the tests. Was hoping for maybe a way to say: "Add this option to the run configuration when it is created for a test-run"